# Assigning closure as default parameter using || throws a syntax error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, closures

I was attempting to assign a closure as a default for an argument and was wondering why the following throws a syntax error:

```js
var myVar, myFunc;
// This throws a syntax error
myVar = myFunc || ()=>{};
console.log(myVar);
```

When the following functionally similar examples work as expected.

```js
var myVar, myFunc, closure;
myVar = (myFunc !== undefined) ? myfunc : ()=>{};
console.log('1.', myVar); // ()=>{}

myVar = myFunc ? myfunc : ()=>{};
console.log('2.', myVar); // ()=>{}

myVar = myFunc || (()=>{});
console.log('3.', myVar); // ()=>{}

myVar = myFunc || function (){};
console.log('4.', myVar); // function(){}

closure = ()=>{};
myVar = myFunc || closure;
console.log('5.', myVar); // ()=>{}
```

I would have expected that assigning a closure would worked as consistently as assigning a function is there a reason why directly combining it with a logical OR throws a syntax error?

Comment: Perhaps it parses as if it was `(myFunc || ()) => {};` which is invalid. That is to say that the `=>` operator has lower precedence than `||`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mentioned as the behavior of arrow function syntax on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Parsing_order), and Mozilla firefox produces the error

> SyntaxError: invalid arrow-function arguments (parentheses around the arrow-function may help)

Parentheses around the arrow function do help. I have not attempted to decipher the content of ECMASript specifications to determine how the syntax is specified in an unreadable manner.

Comment: Thanks :) by the looks it comes down to the fact that closures have different parsing rules that are different from usual operator precedence and different from that of a regular function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by wrapping the arrow function in a bracket

```js
var myVar, myFunc;
myVar = myFunc || (() => {});
console.log(myVar);
```